# How to remove value from vue Inertia form when there is a conditions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

So I have this form that changes whenever user choose which one field they want to fill like this
[image: new data]
[image: existing data]

when the user choose to fill new data, they input a new code, and if the user want to fill the data using existing code they will choose in the `select` field

the problem is there is no telling whether user choose using new data or existing data, the form fields always fill it both, I have tried it using an conditional based on the radio group value (true or false), so I can split it later in controller, but the radio value always true because it takes the value from the default declaration

```
export default {
    components: {
        AuthenticatedLayout,
        PrimaryButton,
        TextInput,
        InputLabel,
    },
    setup() {
        const radioCode = ref(true);
        const form = useForm({
            newData: radioCode,
            image: "",
            codeText: "",
            codeSelect: "",
            description: "",
            category: "",
            woodtype: "",
            width: "",
            depth: "",
            height: "",
            stock: "",
            price: "",
        });

        const submit = () => {
            form.post(route("input.create"));
        };

        return { radioCode, submit, form };
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(event) {
            this.radioCode = !this.radioCode;
            // console.log(this.radioCode);
        },
    },
};
```

Is there any way to do a conditional check when the radio is true, the form data will sends `codeText` and the rest of data without `codeSelect` , and when the radio is false the form data will sends `codeSelect` and removes `codeText` and sends all the rest of data?

**the form**

```
<form @submit.prevent="submit">
                                <div
                                    class="border-1 border-yellow-400 p-2 flex flex-row"
                                >
                                    <div
                                        class="border-1 border-green-500 w-[50%] items-center p-2"
                                    >
                                        <div
                                            class="flex flex-row p-2 border-1 border-cyan-300"
                                        >
                                            <h1 class="m-2">Image :</h1>
                                            <input
                                                id="image"
                                                v-on:change="form.image"
                                                type="file"
                                                class="file-input file-input-sm rounded-md file-input-bordered file-input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div
                                            class="flex flex-row p-2 border-1 border-cyan-300"
                                        >
                                            <h1 class="m-2">Code :</h1>
                                            <div v-if="radioCode">
                                                <input
                                                    id="codeText"
                                                    v-model="form.codeText"
                                                    type="text"
                                                    placeholder="Type here"
                                                    class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                            <div v-else>
                                                <select
                                                    id="codeSelect"
                                                    v-model="form.codeSelect"
                                                    class="select select-md select-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                                >
                                                    <option disabled selected>
                                                        Existing Code
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option>TW-01</option>
                                                    <option>TW-02</option>
                                                    <option>TW-03</option>
                                                    <option>TW-04</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <!-- Radio Group -->
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="ml-5 flex flex-col">
                                                <div class="flex flex-row">
                                                    <input
                                                        type="radio"
                                                        name="radioCode"
                                                        class="mb-2 radio radio-sm radio-primary bg-inherit enabled:hover:border-info enabled:checked:bg-primary"
                                                        value="new"
                                                        @change="
                                                            onChange($event)
                                                        "
                                                        checked
                                                    />
                                                    <label
                                                        for="radio"
                                                        class="ml-2"
                                                        >New data</label
                                                    >
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="flex flex-row">
                                                    <input
                                                        type="radio"
                                                        name="radioCode"
                                                        class="radio radio-sm radio-primary bg-inherit enabled:hover:border-info enabled:checked:bg-primary"
                                                        value="exist"
                                                        @change="
                                                            onChange($event)
                                                        "
                                                    />
                                                    <label
                                                        for="radio"
                                                        class="ml-2"
                                                        >Existing data</label
                                                    >
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div
                                            class="flex flex-row p-2 border-1 border-cyan-300"
                                        >
                                            <h1 class="m-2">Description :</h1>
                                            <input
                                                id="description"
                                                v-model="form.description"
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Type here"
                                                class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div
                                            class="flex flex-row p-2 border-1 border-cyan-300"
                                        >
                                            <h1 class="m-2">Category :</h1>
                                            <select
                                                id="category"
                                                v-model="form.category"
                                                class="select select-md select-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                            >
                                                <option disabled selected>
                                                    Insert category
                                                </option>
                                                <option>Indoor</option>
                                                <option>Outdoor</option>
                                                <option>Handicraft</option>
                                                <option>Root</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div
                                            class="flex flex-row p-2 border-1 border-cyan-300"
                                        >
                                            <h1 class="m-2">Wood Type :</h1>
                                            <select
                                                id="woodtype"
                                                v-model="form.woodtype"
                                                class="select select-md select-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                            >
                                                <option disabled selected>
                                                    Insert wood type
                                                </option>
                                                <option>Teak Wood</option>
                                                <option>Tiger Wood</option>
                                                <option>Mahogany Wood</option>
                                                <option>Root</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div
                                        class="border-1 border-green-500 w-[50%] items-center p-2"
                                    >
                                        <div
                                            class="flex flex-row p-2 border-1 border-cyan-300"
                                        >
                                            <h1 class="m-2">Width :</h1>
                                            <input
                                                id="width"
                                                v-model="form.width"
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Type here"
                                                class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div
                                            class="flex flex-row p-2 border-1 border-cyan-300"
                                        >
                                            <h1 class="m-2">Depth :</h1>
                                            <input
                                                id="depth"
                                                v-model="form.depth"
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Type here"
                                                class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div
                                            class="flex flex-row p-2 border-1 border-cyan-300"
                                        >
                                            <h1 class="m-2">Height :</h1>
                                            <input
                                                id="height"
                                                v-model="form.height"
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Type here"
                                                class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div
                                            class="flex flex-row p-2 border-1 border-cyan-300"
                                        >
                                            <h1 class="m-2">Stock :</h1>
                                            <input
                                                id="stock"
                                                v-model="form.stock"
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Type here"
                                                class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div
                                            class="flex flex-row p-2 border-1 border-cyan-300"
                                        >
                                            <h1 class="m-2">Price :</h1>
                                            <input
                                                id="price"
                                                v-model="form.price"
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Type here"
                                                class="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <PrimaryButton
                                        class="ml-4"
                                        :class="{
                                            'opacity-25': form.processing,
                                        }"
                                        :disabled="form.processing"
                                    >
                                        Input
                                    </PrimaryButton>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

**the js script(vue)**

```
<script>
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue";
import PrimaryButton from "@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue";
import TextInput from "@/Components/TextInput.vue";
import InputLabel from "@/Components/InputLabel.vue";
import { Link, useForm } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import { ref } from "vue";
import InputError from "@/Components/InputError.vue";
export default {
    components: {
        AuthenticatedLayout,
        PrimaryButton,
        TextInput,
        InputLabel,
    },
    setup() {
        const radioCode = ref(true);
        const form = useForm({
            newData: radioCode,
            image: "",
            codeText: "",
            codeSelect: "",
            description: "",
            category: "",
            woodtype: "",
            width: "",
            depth: "",
            height: "",
            stock: "",
            price: "",
        });

        const submit = () => {
            form.post(route("input.create"));
        };

        return { radioCode, submit, form };
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(event) {
            this.radioCode = !this.radioCode;
            // console.log(this.radioCode);
        },
    },
};
</script>
```